# Select_tag wont dispay anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code 
`<%= form_tag('/update', method: :post) do %>
 <%= select_tag :role, UserSomething.roles.keys.map {|role|  [role.titleize,role]} %>`

Role is an enum which text values have to be displayed in the drop down menu, and on form submit, i have to send the index of selected enum to some controller. I don't know how to set select_tag propertly.

Comment: It displays nothing?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or a generated html output?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the helper `options_for_select` to map the array you get from `UserSomething.roles.keys.map` to a list of options for the select. I don't think out the `select_tag` method handles an array of the box, it needs a list of option tags. See the [docs here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag).

```
<%= form_tag('/update', method: :post) do %>
 <%= select_tag :role, options_for_select(UserSomething.roles.keys.map {|role|  [role.titleize,role]}) %>
<% end %>
```